# read settings from a file in gae java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am using some strings in my gae java code,which user has to configure.I know there is way to read settings from a config file which user can edit.Please tell how to do this or provide links for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no filesystem access in GAE.  It's probably best (and easier) to store per user config settings in the datastore.